# If I install lodash.minby does it means it just installs this specific function?

Tags: npm, lodash

I am getting rid of lodash, so some stuff I am redoing in es6 and other like this one I would like to keep but just this one function.

I see there is this npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.minby but im not sure if i install this it will only install this, or the whole library, can anyone please confirm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you install `lodash.minby`, at the time of this writing, you will get version 4.6.0 which contains a `package.json` file, a `README.md` file, a `LICENSE` file, and an `index.js` file. It has no other dependencies, so that is all you will get. The `index.js` file is over 2000 lines long, but that's what it takes apparently to implement the functionality.

In contrast, at the time of this writing, `npm install lodash` will give you version 4.17.21 which contains over 44000 lines of JavaScript spread out across many files. So that's about 22 times as large.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The lodash method `_.minBy` exported as a Node.js module.

So, yes, it just installs this specific function from `lodash`